# i want to edit the specific block of data from a file specified through perl script

Tags: perl, file-io

the file data blocks are in same format like the below file

```
edit_file content{
       val0      data0
       val0      data0
       val0      data0
       val0      data0
       val0      data0
   }
```

and my code is

```
my $temp_hash;
open FD, "<temp.cfg";
@array = <FD>;
foreach $line (@array) {
    if ($line =~ /\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/) {
        foreach $key (keys %tem) {
            $temp_hash{$1} = $2;
        }
    }
    print $temp_hash;
}
foreach $array (keys $1) {
    print "$key is $temp_hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: What is the question? What is not working? Which result do you expect? Be specific!

Comment: where does `%tem` come from? what exactly is that data file? - there may already be something on CPAN to parse such files

Comment: the data file is a configuration file in the above given format and %tem is temporary hash i have declared if u find the given code is wrong can u help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **parse** your file into the hash:

```
my %data;
open my $fh, "<", "temp.cfg" or die $!;
while ( my $line = readline($fh) ) {

    if ( $line =~ m{^\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$} ) {

        $data{$1} = $2;
    }
}
close $fh;

foreach my $key (keys %data) {
    print "$key is $data{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: the file contains several such blocks in it so how to identify a single/specific block of data